# How to use .ord and .chr properly in a loop?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am trying to make a function that takes a jumbled sequence of letters and returns English. For some reason, I can't get `word = (word.ord-4).chr` to work properly. The secret to the code is that the letters are shifted 4 slots backwards, which is why I'm converting it to an integer first, subtracting 4, and then turning it back to a string.

The loop also appears to be ignoring the fact that I told it to skip a word if it's any of those special characters. What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions or sources that will bring me closer to solving this problem?

```
def north_korean_cipher(coded_mesage)
  input = coded_mesage.split('') # splits the coded message into array of letters

  input.each do |word|
    word = (word.ord - 4).chr

    if word == '@' || '#' || '$' || '%' || '^' || '&' || '*'
      next
    end
  end

  print input
end

north_korean_cipher('m^aerx%e&gsoi!')
```

Comment: BTW, you have to *rotate* the alphabet: `a -> w`, `b -> x`, `c -> y`, `d -> z`, `e -> a`, and so on

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Stefan, but isn't rotate only a method of Array?

Comment: `("a".ord - 4).chr` returns `"]"`, not `"w"`. And yes, you could use a rotated array to create your mapping.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I'm learning a lot right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a mapping like this:

```
input:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
output: wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

Unfortunately your approach doesn't work for the first 4 letters:

```
("a".ord - 4).chr #=> "]"
("b".ord - 4).chr #=> "^"
("c".ord - 4).chr #=> "_"
("d".ord - 4).chr #=> "`"
```

I'd use [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-tr). It replaces each occurrence in the first string with the corresponding character in the second string:

```
"m^aerx%e&gsoi!".tr("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv")
#=> "i^want%a&coke!"
```

There's also a *"c1-c2 notation to denote ranges of characters"*:

```
"m^aerx%e&gsoi!".tr("a-z", "w-za-v")
#=> "i^want%a&coke!"
```

The documentation further says:

> If `to_str` is shorter than `from_str`, it is padded with its last character in order to maintain the correspondence.

So it can be used to easily replace the "special characters" with a space:

```
"m^aerx%e&gsoi!".tr("a-z@#$%^&*", "w-za-v ")
#=> "i want a coke!"
```

Comment: You are phenomenal. Best answer I've ever received on StackOverflow. Thank you so much. Is the tr method something you knew, or did you look it up? How can I navigate the documentation more effectively?

Comment: You don't have to know every method from day one. There are many ways to replace characters :)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if word == '@' || '#' || '$' || '%' || '^' || '&' || '*'
```

does not do what you expect it to do, because `'#'` as a condition will always be `true`. You can't compare objects like that. You should do something like

```
if word == '@' || word == '#' || word == '$' || word == '%' || word == '^' || word == '&' || word == '*'
```

You can write it in a more succinct way by asking:

```
if %w(@ # $ % ^ & *).include? word
```

Which checks if `word` is in the collection of options...